# How to scale text in html?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, web

Hello I was wondering how to scale text with html. My text looks very large when I make the page smaller. Is there a script or a command that will scale the text down along with the page size?

Comment: Can you provide more detail in your question? Do you have viewport meta data in your page? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Comment: You shouldn't enforce text sizes on anyone. As Neal said below, use font-size to set it, but don't rely on it always looking pixel perfect like that as some people set text to be larger or smaller for accessibilty reasons. Also browsers sometimes display fonts differently so it may look different on any individuals computer.

Comment: Just hit `Ctrl` and `+`.

Comment: Does this help: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/controlling_text_size_in_safari_for_ios_without_disabling_user_zoom/  I agree the question is hard to understand...do you mean you do NOT want the text to scale up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has me a little confused, but it may just be the way you are phrasing it.

Are you saying that you want the browser to "resize" text, headers, and other content depending on the browser size?

If so, what you are referring to is called responsive design.

**Here is a DEMO of a site using this responsive design.**  (Make the screen bigger/smaller, and let me know if this is what you were trying to achieve)

http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/adaptive-design/final.html

Here is the tutorial behind this demo:
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

Comment: Tried the demo just for fun and it didn't work as you described.

Comment: Yes I would also like to do this with my images

Comment: The demo i Provided you will also handle images

Comment: The text seems to have the same font size no matter how big or small the window is.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use css to change the `font-size`, if that is what you are referring to.